# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined : PHP PDO Object

Tags: php, mysql

I know this error is answered before but I am not able to solve the problem in my code.

Here's my code:

```
//Basic SELECT query
$select = 'SELECT id, joketext';
$from = ' FROM joke';
$where = ' WHERE TRUE';

$placeholders = array();

if ($_GET['author'] != ' ') //author is selected
{
    $where .= 'AND authorid = :authorid';
    $placeholders[':authorid'] = $_GET['author'];
}

if ($_GET['category'] != ' ') //category is selected
{
    $from .= 'INNET SELECT jokecategory ON id = jokeid';
    $where .= 'AND categoryid = :categoryid';
    $placeholders[':categoryid'] = $_GET['category'];
}

if ($_GET['text'] != ' ') //text was specified
{
    $where .= 'AND joketext LIKE :joketext';
    $placeholders[':joketext'] = '%' . $_GET['text'] . '%';
}

try
{
    $sql = $select . $from . $where;
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->execute($placeholders);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error fetching jokes.' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.php';
    exit();
}
```

I would appreciate if someone explained me why this error usually comes?
Thanks!

Comment: Use `var_dump($sql, $placeholders)` to see what you actually got.

Comment: `INNET SELECT`? since when is that valid sql? `INNER JOIN` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put spaces before each addition to `$where` and `$from`.

```
if ($_GET['author'] != ' ') //author is selected
{
    $where .= ' AND authorid = :authorid';
    $placeholders[':authorid'] = $_GET['author'];
}

if ($_GET['category'] != ' ') //category is selected
{
    $from .= ' INNER JOIN jokecategory ON id = jokeid';
    $where .= ' AND categoryid = :categoryid';
    $placeholders[':categoryid'] = $_GET['category'];
}

if ($_GET['text'] != ' ') //text was specified
{
    $where .= ' AND joketext LIKE :joketext';
    $placeholders[':joketext'] = '%' . $_GET['text'] . '%';
}
```

If you don't do this, you get a query that looks like:

```
SELECT id, joketext FROM joke WHERE TRUEAND authorid = :authoridANDjoketext = :joketext
```